# email address not accepted in username of a particular user record, even though its never used

Tags: user-record, user-admin

I need to add my company's email address to my user record in Company's Production org. While I am trying to do so, I am getting an error that this email address is already in use. I checked everywhere(personal dev org, sandbox, production) but it's not visible to be used in any of these.
As an alternative, I put this username at login.salesforce.com and hit forgot password. An email came to reset my password and the **base url is of my personal dev org**. I am however not able to reset it as System is not accepting the answer to security question. I logged in to my personal dev org with another user as System Administrator, but still I can't see any user with the username of my company's email address.
I need to update that user record with some other username in my personal dev org and it is urgently needed. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: As you mentioned you were able to login as a system admin try checking if you are able to receive a user id with the username.

Comment: Got the issue resolved by raising case with Salesforce Support. They reset the username with some other value.